# Creating multiple links inside a href

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

This is the a litle piece from a menu:

```
<li><a href="onelink.html">Some Text </a>
```

Now I want that after SOME TEXT to be 1 2 3 and when I click 1 2 3 to link me to another link, it has to be inside the `>Some Text </a>`.

Some ideas?

Comment: do you want the text to change? i don't get what you're asking

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Why does this other link need to be inside `>Some Text</a>`?

Comment: no i do not want that the text to be changed, http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/# this is the menu that i use, and when i press that numbers they represents Years, so i click one 1 and i will be redirected to Year 1 , Year 2 and so on

Comment: You can't have a link inside another link...

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/pqz6W/)? If not, try to me more specific.

Comment: so you want a drop down menu? that link isn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you are searching for:

```
    <ul id="mega-menu-1" class="mega-menu">
        <li><a href="test.html">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="in_a_row" href="#">Coupe
                            <div class="cars">
                                <a class="car" href="#">1</a>
                                <a class="car" href="#">2</a>
                                <a class="car" href="#">3</a>
                            </div>
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

For styling of the elements you can use this CSS code:

```
    .cars,
    .car,
    #in_a_row
    {
        display: inline !important;
    }
```

Use `!important` to overwrite styles which have been defined by the plugins CSS file.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/RSwy6zXh) you can grab the source code. Just replace the `index.html` of the plugin with that code.

Comment: it would appear under the first one

Comment: here is the code for the menu that i use http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/#

Comment: what do you mean by 'it would appear under the first one' exactly. Maybe this will help you: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/

Comment: visit that link that i provided , and there you have Vehicles and at Vehicles we have Coupe , now next to Coupe i wish to have a text that when i press on it to be redirected to another page , for example 1 2 3 , to appear exactly next to Coupe and this numbers to be links .

Comment: Was this the solution you searched for?

Comment: I on mobile where i can accept your answer? I am new at this:)

Comment: On the left side of my answer should be a checkmark. The question has at the same position a star, where you could mark the question as a favorite. :)